# php curl login to instagram goes into redirection loop

Tags: php, curl, instagram

I'm logging into instagram with curl and php and it goes in a redirection loop where a text similar to this is echoed with few variations between each echo

```
> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently Location: https://www.instagram.com/
> Content-Type: text/plain Server: proxygen Date: Mon, 16 Jan 2017
> 12:53:26 GMT Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 0
> 
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: text/html Vary: Cookie, Accept-Language,
> Accept-Encoding Content-Language: en Pragma: no-cache Expires: Sat, 01
> Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=86400 Date:
> Mon, 16 Jan 2017 12:53:27 GMT X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
> Content-Encoding: gzip Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store,
> must-revalidate Set-Cookie: sessionid=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970
> 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/; HttpOnly; Domain=instagram.com
> Set-Cookie: csrftoken=uWHWfgmVVhdROoG3HsyIevXMq4mcEGVU; expires=Mon,
> 15-Jan-2018 12:53:27 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure Connection:
> keep-alive Content-Length: 3373
```

the code I'm using is this

```
<?php

    include_once('simple_html_dom.php'); 

        $usuario = "username";
        $password = "password";

        $url = 'https://www.instagram.com/';
        $url_login = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/';
        $user_agent = array("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 ",
                      "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36");

        $ch = curl_init(); 

        $headers = [
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
        'Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Content-Length: 0',
        'Host: www.instagram.com',
        'Origin: https://www.instagram.com',
        'Referer: https://www.instagram.com/',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36', 
        'X-Instagram-AJAX: 1',
        'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'  
        ];

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie/pruebalogininsta3.txt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $sTarget);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);

        $html = curl_exec($ch);

        preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $html, $matches);
        $cookies = array();
        foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
            parse_str($item, $cookie);
            $cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
        }


        $headers = [
        'Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Content-Length: 0',
        'Host: www.instagram.com',
        'Origin: https://www.instagram.com',
        'Referer: https://www.instagram.com/',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36', 
        'X-Instagram-AJAX: 1',
        'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'
        ];

        $cadena_agregar_vector = 'X-CSRFToken:'. $cookies["csrftoken"];

        $headers[] = $cadena_agregar_vector ;

        $sPost=http_build_query(array('username'=>$usuario,'password'=>$password));


        # Creo que falta agregar la variable POST para que mande un POST y no un GET

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sPost);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_login);  

        $html2 = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.instagram.com/");  

        $html4 = curl_exec($ch);

        echo $html4;

    ?>
```

Comment: are you aware that you posted a real username/password combination publicly on stackoverflow? i hope that this @pablodalmazzo account can be compromised without issues, like the throwaway account i posted. if not, you should change your password asap.

Comment: thanks, I didnt notice, there is nothing important there though

Comment: be aware that the username/password is still visible if you check the edit history, publicly available at http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41676960/revisions - you should change your password

Comment: thanks, already did when I first saw your comment.

Answer (score 2):

you do a couple of mistakes,

1: you add the `'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',` header manually. should the server chose to actually use gzip/deflate, the response body would look all garbled (binary compressed data), if you want to use compression in curl, use `CURLOPT_ENCODING` instead, and curl will decompress it for you. (at least you do it correctly in the 2nd call)

2: you add the `Referer: https://www.instagram.com/` , only to overwrite it moments later with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $sTarget);` , making the custom header ignored, AND $sTarget seems to be an undefined variable.

3: you use captial letters in your http headers. the login protocol does not use capital letters in any headers, as far as i can see. (for example, you call it `X-Instagram-AJAX: 1` , but the login page calls it `x-instagram-ajax: 1`)

using hhb_curl from https://github.com/divinity76/hhb_.inc.php/blob/master/hhb_.inc.php ,

here's a working example code:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);
require_once('hhb_.inc.php');
$hc = new hhb_curl ();
$hc->_setComfortableOptions ();

$username = 'nigeriansdddd';
$password = '3fc2p4xy049q3om@my10minutemail.com';
// get a cookie session and login page etc
$hc->exec ( 'https://www.instagram.com/' );
// hhb_var_dump($hc->getStdErr(),$hc->getResponseBody());
$html = $hc->getResponseBody ();
$token = getCsrfToken ( $html );
$hc->setopt_array ( array (
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/',
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                'x-csrftoken: ' . $token,
                'x-instagram-ajax: 1',
                'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest',
                'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nb;q=0.6',
                'origin: https://www.instagram.com',
                'referer: https://www.instagram.com/' 
        )
        ,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query ( array (
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password 
        ) ) 
) );
$hc->exec ();
// hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getResponseBody () );
$jsonRAW = $hc->getResponseBody ();
$json = json_decode ( $jsonRAW, true );
if (! is_array ( $json ) || $json ['status'] !== 'ok' || $json ['authenticated'] !== true) {
    throw new RuntimeException ( 'failed to login. last curl request: ' . $hc->getStdErr () . $hc->getResponseBody () );
}
$hc->exec ( 'https://www.instagram.com/' );
$html = $hc->getResponseBody ();
if (false === strpos ( $html, $username )) {
    throw new RuntimeException ( 'failed to confirm login. last curl request: ' . $hc->getStdErr () . $hc->getResponseBody () );
}
hhb_var_dump ( $hc->getStdErr (), $hc->getResponseBody () );


function getCsrfToken(string $html): string {
    $matches = array ();
    $rexret = preg_match ( '/\"csrf_token\"\s*\:\s*\"([^\"]*)/', $html, $matches );
    if ($rexret !== 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException ( 'failed to find the csrf token!' );
    }
    // hhb_var_dump($rexret,$matches);
    $csrftoken = $matches [1];
    return $csrftoken;
}
```

(note: the account, `nigeriansdddd` / `3fc2p4xy049q3om@my10minutemail.com` is just a dummy throwaway account, i don't care if the account is compromised, which obviously happens when i post the credentials here)

Comment: I tried the code, but it doesnt seem to be working. Shouldnt I get the main feed after logging in?. I created an account in a hosting with php7, because that library requires php7, but I got the same result, here it is https://yotambienmerio.000webhostapp.com/phpversion.png and after a second call to the file it triggers a fatal error here you can see https://yotambienmerio.000webhostapp.com/codigo_del_pibe.php

Comment: @Pablo yes you should get the main page. strange, it works for me. seems that it fails on `if (! is_array ( $json ) || $json ['status'] !== 'ok' || $json ['authenticated'] !== true) {` , replace that code with `if (! is_array ( $json ) || $json ['status'] !== 'ok' || $json ['authenticated'] !== true) {
hhb_var_dump($hc->getStdErr () , $hc->getResponseBody ());
    throw new RuntimeException ( 'failed to login. see stdout' );
}`, and run it again, what do you get?

Comment: @Pablo strange, my test account was deleted it seems, `The username you entered doesn't belong to an account. Please check your username and try again.` - no wonder the test code doesn't work with that account, did you test it with a working account?

Comment: I've tried with another account, same result as the one in the screencapture.

Comment: may be instagram changed something since you've made that code

Comment: @Pablo well, i dont have an account to test with now, and their register website is bugged (as far as i can see, its not possible to create new accounts right now), so cannot check what it is