# Browser opens a link successfully, but not curl and file_get_contents

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to use Instagram API. when I open following link in browser, it's completely fine an you can click on it and see the json response:
https://www.instagram.com/nasa/?__a=1

When I tried to open the same url via `file_get_contents()` I faced 403 Forbidden Error.

So I tried to use curl. here is my code :

```
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/nasa/?__a=1";
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


var_dump($result);
```

The problem is `$result` is an empty string. When I try to get contents using file_get_contents, I face 403 Forbidden Error, and when I try to get contents using curl it return an empty string.

Can Some body help? Tnx.

**Edit**
I dont get 403 Forbidden in my browser because I'm logged in.

Comment: When I try to open the url on the browser I get a 403 Error, so it must be that you have to be authenticated to get the content. You probably don't get the error on your browser because you are log in.

Comment: @nerea yes, i checked and i am logged in. I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

you need to enable cookie support (eg CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE) AND log in before you can access https://www.instagram.com/nasa/?__a=1 , and your curl code never attempts to log in.

here you can see how to log in to Instagram with PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41684531/1067003