# Instagram login through curl

Tags: curl, http-post

Instaloader ( a kind of instagram **scraper** ) working fine for me. And then i decided to replicate the same using curl but i am stuck.

[Here](https://github.com/instaloader/instaloader/blob/f09bd51ed416710b47226b3e91faefa14c85e91a/instaloader/instaloadercontext.py#L222) is line of code from instaloader , i am following for my curl POST request to instagram

```
curl -v -L -X POST -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Redmi Note 7 Pro) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Mobile Safari/537.36" \
 -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" \
 -H "Referer: https://www.instagram.com/" \
 -H "Connection: keep-alive" \ 
 -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" \
 -H "Host: www.instagram.com" \
 -H "Origin: https://www.instagram.com" \
 -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" \
 -H "x-csrftoken: Bk67CZMxGjj63HqhSSDoCRiRJWWM3Oay" \
 -H "X-Instagram-AJAX: 1" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{"username": "dcent_07", "enc_password": "#PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER:0:current_timestamp:mypassword_goes_here"}' \
 https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/
```

I am receiving json rresponse like this

```
{"user":false,"authenticated":false,"status":"ok"}
```

Then i thought, maybe there is something wrong with header ? Then i just added a print statement after post request in orginal instaloader source and i got

```
{'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36', 
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
'Accept': '*/*', 
'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8', 
'Content-Length': '0', 
'Host': 'www.instagram.com', 
'Origin': 'https://www.instagram.com', 
'Referer': 'https://www.instagram.com/', 
'X-Instagram-AJAX': '1', 
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 
'X-CSRFToken': 'OTyiskTUqTv74s6csIJy7NmcweNj2ULW'}
```

Comment: you don't. Instagram's login procedures is far too complex to run with curl alone. use a scripting language with libcurl bindings, like python, php, perl, whatever. not just curl.

Comment: but what is problem in that ? curl used libcurl itself. btw what is too complex in this ? its just a simple post request.

Comment: It's not "just a post" - just a quick look with chrome devtools on the login request suggests it requires cookie handling, HTML parsing (for the csrf token), url-encoding, base64 encoding, and god knows what else

Comment: btw i wrote an instagram login script in PHP back in 2017: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676960/php-curl-login-to-instagram-goes-into-redirection-loop/41684531#41684531

Comment: i can get csrf token easily with curl, and when i am looking into source of instaloader i can't see any encoding done by author